# How to define template function in source file

Tags: c++, templates

How can I declare template function in header file and define in source file?

```
// foo.h
template<typename T>
bool foo();

// foo.cpp
template<typename T>
bool foo()
{
    return false;
}

// main.cpp
bool bar = foo<int>();
```

I've got this so far. It compiles, but fails at linker: *"undefined reference to `bool foo<int>()`"*

Comment: See the following: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But there is a workaround if you really want seperate files:

**Foo.tpp**

```
template<typename T> void foo()
{

}
```

**Foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP_
#define FOO_HPP_

template<typename T>
void foo();

#include "Foo.tpp";

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
}
```

Basically you put the implementation in a seperate file that is not recognised by the compiler, and you include that at the end of your header.